# can not resolve getcontext()

Tags: java, android

error show in UserAdapter list.getContext() can not be resolve in that program please review this problem and solve that problem.
that code posted please review code and give suggestion for this project.
i have posted the Chat_frg code and this code below post Users.class code.

```
package fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.UserAdapter;
import com.example.myapplication.Users;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Chat_frg extends Fragment {
public Chat_frg(){

}
ArrayList<Users> list=new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseDatabase database;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
    UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(list.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_frg, container, false);
    }
}
```

Users.java class review this class

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class Users {
    String ProfilePic,Name,phoneNumber,Email,password,userId,lastMessage,status;

    public Users(){

    }

    public Users(String profilePic, String name, String phoneNumber, String email, String password, String userId, String lastMessage, String status) {
        ProfilePic = profilePic;
        Name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        Email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Users(String name, String email, String password) {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return ProfilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        ProfilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `Users` data model

Comment: Most probably, you don't have a `getContext()` inside your `Users` data model which you are trying to access.

Comment: i have posted 'Users' data model.

Comment: `getActivity()` also can not resolve

Comment: You are not using the layoutManager in your recylerView. Make sure you set the layout manager. Like `recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( getActivity()) );` or `recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( getContext()) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I'm confused about this code:

```
ArrayList<Users> list=new ArrayList<>();
...
UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(list.getContext());
```

The `list` is an instance of ArrayList, in general, it doesn't relate to Context, but you still call `list.getContext()`, it seems that you want to pass a context to class UserAdapter.

If you want to use the Context in class UserAdpater you can pass `getActivity()` or `getContext()`, of course, you should have the property `Context context` in UserAdapter firstly.

```
class UserAdapter{
    private Context context;
    UserAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}

UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity() or getContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

i am solve that issue
`list.getContext` can not resolve.
i have to replace `list.getContext()` with `list,getContext()`

like this

```
UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(list,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```